# How do I write a function for accessing elements of a list in R using for loops?

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function `for_over_list(n)` that uses `for` statements to sum all the elements in `my_list` using each of R's two list accessing methods:

1. Accessing by the element of the list
2. By the position number of the list

In order to access a list element by its position number i know to use double-brackets, i.e., `my_list[[2]]`.

In order to solve this, I want to apply the `sum()` function to each element of the list, as I iterate over the list elements. This is what I have so far, but obviously it does not work. I know there are many more efficient ways to do this, but I'm hoping to approach this problem from a very naive perspective.

```
for_over_list<- function(n=2) {

  my_list <- list(c(1:n), rep(1,n))

  sum_by_element <- 0
  sum_by_position <- 0

  # Code the for-loop that sums by element
  for(elem in my_list){
    sum_by_element <- sum(my_list[[elem]])
  }

  # Code the for-loop that sums by position number
  for(pos in my_list){
    sum_by_position <- sum(my_list[[pos]])
  }  

  # Return the resulting sums as a named list
  list(element=sum_by_element, position=sum_by_position)

}
```

Comment: could you please provide a minimal example, and a desired output ?

Comment: Maybe you want (in your loops) `sum_by_element = sum(c(sum_by_element, my_list[[elem]]))`? As-is, you're writing over `sum_by_element` each time through the loop. The same applies to `sum_by_position`.

Comment: I think the first thing you should notice is that the code for your two loops is identical. The variable names are different, but you're doing the same thing. (That it's probably not the thing you want to be doing is a different issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're going for -- using each method, this produces a vectors as output, where each element in the vector is the sum of the elements at the corresponding position in `my_list`. I've split them up to make things a little easier.

In this one, you're iterating over the elements *themselves* -- you don't have to index into the list, because you already have what you want.

```
sum_by_element = c()
for(elem in my_list){
    sum_by_element = c(sum_by_element, sum(elem))
}
```

In this one, you're iterating over the *indices* of the elements -- meaning you *do* have to index into the list with it, using the `[[` notation you mention.

```
sum_by_position = c()
for(index in 1:length(my_list)){
    sum_by_position = c(sum_by_position, sum(my_list[[index]])
}
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: One would think that you would not use `c` but rather `sum` and init at 0.

Comment: I believe that's a different understanding of the problem -- I understand the question as asking for summing each _element_ in the list, not getting an overall sum for the entire data structure. That's why the list is composed of vectors, not single values.

Comment: In which case one would be advised to pre-allocate a list or numeric vector of the correct length and then place the indexed sums by name or number. Using for-loops to extend objects incrementally is the most inefficient approach possible.

Comment: From the posed question: "I know there are many more efficient ways to do this, but I'm hoping to approach this problem from a very naive perspective." I wanted to add as few elements as possible, and am also aware of the efficiency differences.

Answer (score 0):

OK, failing at getting recognition of my comments, I'll post the recommended way of using for-loops on this two part problem on the assumption that individual rather than total sums are what are desired.

```
for_sum_names <- function(L) {
    res <- vector("numeric", length(L) )
    for( i in names(L) ) {
            res[i] <- sum( L[[i]] ) }
    return(res)
    ) 

for_sum_nums <- function(L) {
    res <- vector("numeric", length(L) )
    for( i in seq_along(L) ) {
            res[i] <- sum( L[[i]] ) }
    return(res)
    )
```